# Using knitr, beamer, and /foreach to produce unique section titles in pdf from R string variable

Tags: beamer, loops, foreach, knitr

Using R, knitr, and beamer, I have created a pdf that contains a graph for each school in our district.  I read in each graph using the \includegraphics command within a /foreach loop.  I want to create a unique section name for each school using the R-variable 'school'.  I want this section name to appear in the left hand Table of Contents. Relevant code is below.  Thanks.

```
\foreach \i in {1,...,\Sexpr{length(school)}} {%
\section{\Sexpr{school[i]}}    %%% Here is where it is breaking down
\begin{frame}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{plot_\i.pdf}
\end{frame}%
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use variable `\i`, which is TeX variable.  The problem is, R knows nothing about it.  Since  R runs before TeX,  your loop never reaches R.

Instead you can make the loop in R.  The R code should produce the  TeX code.  You need to output results in the `asis` mode, and suppress the code itself.

This works for me:

```
<<echo=FALSE,results='asis'>>=
for (i in 1:length(school)) {  
  cat(paste("\\section{",school[i],"}\n",sep=""))
  cat("\\begin{frame}\n")
  cat(paste("\\includegraphics[width=\\textwidth,",
            "height=\\textheight,keepaspectratio]{plot_",
            i, ".pdf}\n", sep=""))
  cat("\\end{frame}\n")
}
@
```

Each `cat` forms a TeX line which is included in the TeX file;  chunk options make the code invisible to TeX and the results sent 'as is'

Comment: That is correct. People often mix R programming with LaTeX programming, which is not possible in knitr. R/knitr knows nothing about LaTeX programs.